# Python Pandas: Sort and group by, then sum two consecutive rows of 2nd column for a specific value of a 3rd column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, aggregate

I have this dataframe:

```
    Group   Turn    Name
0   G1       1      Maria
1   G1       2      Sam
2   G1       2      Sara
3   G1       3      Maria
4   G1       4      Mark
5   G1       5      Maria

6   G2       2      Maria
7   G2       1      Ahmad

8   G3       1      Maria
9   G3       2      David
```

I would like to group by my data based on value of column "group" and sort based on their "Turn". So with each group the turns are sorted.

Then I would like to sum the value of column "Turn" in each group for the rows where the name is "Maria" and one row after. IF Maria is the last turn in the group then the sum only 
 Maria's turn.

```
So the result looks like this:
    Group       Name    Sum 
        G1      Maria    3
        G1      Maria    7
        G1      Maria    5
        G2      Maria    2
        G3      Maria    3
```

I tried group by and apply and shift but none of them gives me the final result I am looking for.

```
 df = df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Turn'))
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Will `Maria` only ever occur once in each group?

Comment: Could you please post the  code you tried it with? A complete code to start with?

Comment: @ALollz no could be more

Comment: Well you may want to expand upon that logic. How do you want to handle Maria, David Maria, David in the same group in that turn order (are we summing all 4, or only after the first or last occurrence?) What should happen when Maria is the person with the last turn?

Comment: Yes good point. I am gonna edit the question

Comment: You say "and the row after", where row is singular.  Do you actually mean _all_ rows in that group after Maria, or exactly the one next row (assuming it exists)?

Comment: @DSM no only 1 row after

Comment: You've substantially changed the question, which invalidates existing answers.  This is generally considered poor form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `ffill` with `limit`

```
df=df.sort_values(['Group','Turn'])
df[df.Name.where(df.Name=='Maria').groupby(df['Group']).ffill(limit=1).eq('Maria')].set_index('Group').Turn.sum(level=0)
Out[272]: 
Group
G1    5
G2    3
G3    3
Name: Turn, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  If you add an extra non-Maria row at the bottom of the test df, it'll still be treated as Maria, because limit=2. Did you mean limit = 1?

Comment: @DSM yep , should be one :-) fixed

Comment: @Wen Could I also when group by 'group' also sort the turns within the group before summing?

Comment: @UserYmY yes you can

Comment: @wen could you please add in to the solution?

Comment: @UserYmY you do not need groupby sort , just sort_values is good enough

Comment: @Wem I have noticed the solution does not cover situations where there are two maria in a group?right?

Comment: @UserYmY it will cover since you have limit =1 which means Ma NaN NaN Ma NaN will become Ma Ma NaN Ma Ma

Comment: Indeed. Ok I figured out. What it does not do properly is the sorting within the group. The group is a string so, this way of sorting does not sort "Turn" within each group. It sorts all turns in general, right?

Comment: @UserYmY `df.sort_values(['Group','Turn'])` this sort the group first then sort the Turn within the group

Comment: @Wem You are right. It does not work yet and i am trying to find why. I understood  that when Maria is the first and the last in a group, it does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177589/discussion-between-userymy-and-wen).

Comment: @UserYmY you can just check Scott 's answer

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df.set_index(['Group','Name',(df['Name'] == 'Maria').cumsum().rename('Occurance')])\
  .sum(level=[0,2])\
  .reset_index()\
  .assign(name='Maria')\
  .drop('Occurance', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Group  Turn   name
0    G1     3  Maria
1    G1     7  Maria
2    G1     5  Maria
3    G2     3  Maria
4    G3     3  Maria
```

Comment: I've asked the OP for clarification, but the question's title says "_two_ consecutive rows of 2nd column", suggesting that cummax isn't going to work.

Comment: @Scott this gives the TypeError: 'str' object is not callable if I remove the slasesh and connect them in a line

Comment: @Scott, this does not only get one row after maria. IT sums all not Maria rows after Maria.